# session time out handling

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm calling a controllr action through jquery load which works perfect..it blocks the UI untill the data comes from action.

But when session time out then below code throw unhandled error...how to handle error here...please help...

```
 //block the UI until the request is rendered
    $.blockUI({ message: '<h3><b><img src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/loading.gif")" /> Please wait while the request is being processed...</b></h3>' });

    //load partial view contain grid
    $('#rptPOSList').load('@Url.Action("POSListData", "Reports")', { activePOS: ActivePOS, inactivePOS: InActivePOS }, function () {
        $('#contentDiv').show();
        //unblock the UI     
        $.unblockUI();
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) which allows you to specify an error handler:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("POSListData", "Reports")',
    data: { activePOS: ActivePOS, inactivePOS: InActivePOS },
    success: function(result) {
        $('#rptPOSList').html(result);
        $('#contentDiv').show();
        $.unblockUI();
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('oops something went wrong');
    }
});
```

Or if it is only a matter of unblocking the UI no matter whether the AJAX call succeeded or not you could use the `complete` callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("POSListData", "Reports")',
    data: { activePOS: ActivePOS, inactivePOS: InActivePOS },
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        $.unblockUI();
    },
    success: function(result) {
        $('#rptPOSList').html(result);
        $('#contentDiv').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: in case of session time out, it not going to the "error"..I'm loading a partial view here....

Comment: @user584018, you said that an unhandled exception is thrown in your controller if session times out. If this is not the case where is it going then?

Comment: whwn session is not out, then whole partial view data (html format) comes in "result" and when session is out, then a different html is returns..not goes to "error"...any help..please!

Comment: @user584018, where is the server redirecting to when your session times out? You could include a custom HTTP response header in this action and then in the success callback test the presence of this HTTP header which would indicate you that the session timed out.

Comment: how to add custom HTTP response header and how to pick that in success callback..any sample code/link will be appreciated...please help...

Comment: @user584018, to add a custom HTTP response header: `Response.AppendHeader("MyHeader", "foo_bar");`. And to read this HTTP response header: `success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { var myHeader = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('MyHeader'); }`